# How to retrieve authData from a ParseUser?

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrieve the authData field from a ParseUser. With Parse 1.9.1, I used to do it like so:

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
HashMap authDataMap = (HashMap)user.get("authData");
HashMap facebookMap = (HashMap)authDataMap.get("facebook");
String facebookId = (String)facebookMap.get("id");
```

And this worked fine.

Something changed though. I don't know if it's because I updated to Parse 1.9.2 or if something changed on the Parse server side, but authData is no longer accessible. The line user.get("authData") returns null. Even if I re-fetch the user.

Ultimately I want to retrieve the Facebook id from the ParseUser, preferably without reaching out to Facebook. Is this no longer possible?

Comment: Are you using ParseFacebookUtils for login Facebook user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ParseFacebookUtils to perform login Facebook user then after successfully login from in parse try to get GraphUser using following to fetch Facebook user data-

```
                    Request.newMeRequest(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(),
                            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(
                                        final GraphUser fbUser,
                                        Response response) {

                                    try {

                                        if (fbUser != null
                                                && parseUser != null
                                                && fbUser.getName()
                                                        .length() > 0) {

                                          // Facebook user data
                                          String fbId = fbUser.getId();

                                        } else {
                                          // Facebook user not logged in
                                        }
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        stopLoading();

                                    }
                                }
                            }).executeAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks. I suppose authData just isn't accessible anymore. So now I'll have to make two async requests, the Facebook login, and the Facebook ID retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [Facebook Users](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#users-facebook-users) section in the Parse.com documentation. I think authData is for internal communication, not meant to be called (any more).